# Having trouble creating a Laravel query

Tags: sql, forms, select, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to create a form select box in Laravel 4.

There are 3 models in play: User, Band, and Album.

I have the eloquent relationships set up and working as follows:

- A User hasMany Band
- A Band hasMany User
- A Band hasMany Album
- An Album belongsTo a Band

How do I create an array $albums:

```
$userid = Auth::user()->id;
$albums = Album::where(the band the album belongs to has a user with id = $userid);
```

I can't seem to figure this out.

Should I instead create a many-to-many relationship between albums and users, so I can construct an easier query such as $albums = $user->albums;

I'd prefer not having to create another many-to-many relationship, as that's a whole new level of DB management to clutter things up.

Thanks for your assistance!
~Ross

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$user = Auth::user();
$albums = new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
foreach($user->bands as $band){
    $albums = $albums->merge($band->albums);
}
```

Comment: Fantastic, that works great thankyou! I would give you a vote up but don't have the required reputation.. Thanks again! I never would have figured that out.

Comment: No problem. I can live without the upvote. And you can always come back if you have enough ;)

Comment: Hi lukasgeiter, I ran into a problem when the user had more than one band. Resolved it by moving the ->lists function to occur after the foreach loop had completed iterating. Thanks again!

Comment: Well if you only want the id and title you need to use lists() however my answer still answers your question and I don't understand why you unaccepted it...

Comment: Hi, I didn't mean to unaccept the answer, sorry, not sure how that happened. Your answer unfortunately didn't work correctly when a user has more than one band, for some reason it didn't iterate and add the info to the array, it just threw up an error. By moving the lists() command out of the foreach loop it seemed to fix the problem, see my answer below. Thanks, and sorry.

Answer (score 0):

lukasgeiter almost had the correct answer, the only problem was with more than one band it threw up an error. I fixed it by merging the $band->albums in the foreach loop, and then creating the list array when the loop had completed.

```
$albumcheck = new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
  foreach($user->bands as $band){
    $albumcheck = $albumcheck->merge($band->albums);
  }
$albums = $albumcheck->lists('title', 'id');
```